# FormControlName in ax 2012

Tags: forms, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

is it possible to find the control name for control which is an edit method in ax 2012 form.
i.e how to find control name for edit method control.

I tried but could not find the correct name .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on the edit method and click "view details" and it will show you something like `Fld_23` in the lower right corner.

Or if you need to dynamically determine this, I wrote a blogpost on how to recursively enumerate every control on the form. http://alexondax.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-use-recursion-to-loop-over-form.html

The controls are generated at runtime and there is a variable counter that just counts up as each new dynamic control is added during form runtime.  So you can use the name you discover, as long as the form doesn't keep getting modified.  It might be a good idea to just obtain the static group object or whatever that contains the edit method, then just find the child from there.

Answer (score 0):

You must Right Click on form and click on Personalize option.
In personalization form , Goto information tab and Click on Edit form name.
Then You can see and edit form controls in AOT.
You can use below link for more information.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa597239.aspx